# td sticky invisible border - how to fix

Tags: html, css

I have table with `sticky` `<td>`'s as header. Table's `<tr>` and `<thead>` cant be sticky =(

Issue is while header go sticky, borders became invisible. And it appears as padding.

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
border:3px solid gray;
padding:3px;
}

tbody td{
  background:lightgreen;
}
.sticky{
  background:maroon;
  color:white;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made some researsh and I found this :
 `border-spacing: 0; *border-collapse: collapse;` and it worked.

```css
table{
  border-spacing: 0; *border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
border:3px solid gray;
padding:3px;
}

tbody td{
  background:lightgreen;
}
.sticky{
  background:maroon;
  color:white;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header</td>
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header</td>
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header</td>
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header</td>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some random text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, this partially fixing issue, but result in double borders. 1px became 2px, 2px became 4px. Because borders doesn't collapse. I can try to fix it with set not all borders, though.

Answer (score 1):

Add `border-collapse: separate;` to the table instead and it will fix your problem. It will fashion your borders to sit on the `<td>`, the borders will truly attach to the `<td>`, and appear `collapsed`.

**Updated:** add also `border-spacing: 0;` to table to not have any padding for the table cells.

```css
table{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td{
border:3px solid gray;
padding:3px;
}

tbody td{
  background:lightgreen;
}
.sticky{
  background:maroon;
  color:white;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
      <td class="sticky">This is sticky header
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
    <tr><td>Some random text
</table>
```

Comment: But i dont need empty space between cells =\
I need exactly that design i mentioned.

Comment: Updated post, was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Almost, but without "double" borders. This can be fixed though by setting borders to only one side of cell.